# How to write json not from root in android?

Tags: android, json

I want to use json to store log data stream. For example:

```
{
"device" : "device1",
"events" : [ {event1}, {event2} ...]
}
```

Every time I write a event object and save to file. Next time user boot the device, I need to continue the "events" array and write other events until it reach a threshold. After threshold, I will complete the json file by adding "]}" , and maybe with other attributes, then send to server.

I looked JsonWriter which normally used to write json data stream. But it can only write from root, rather not continue last work.

Comment: Why use a json file for this and not sqllite?

Comment: Every event type has different fields except a few common ones. And there'll be new event types as time is going. sqlite cannot create dynamic columns though it has dynamic data types.

Comment: Then wouldn't it be possible to make a Table named "EVENT". Which has the common fields. Then make a table named "EVENT_TYPE" which will contain the extra fields. Make a relationship between the 2 tables.
Then you can dynamically add columns to your EVENT_TYPE with the alter table statement.

I really dont see a reason why anything can be saved in json and not in a sqllite database. You should also keep in mind that in Android applications have only read access to the sd card. Even Samsung changed their policy in no longer allowing that.

Comment: Ideally yes, it can be save that way in sqlite, though it will add unknown amount of fields in a table. I'm not sure whether RDBMS is designed to be used that way. Another point, I don't need to query or update the data. It's log following a timeline. I only need to send it to server. The reason I use Json is for scalable and readable. Some db can store json too, mangodb for example.

Comment: Finally I wrote a simple json writer which will check first level state. For example, it'll only check what are allowed to follow "{", it has to be a name. but it won't check the stack.